# GreenDroid import problem

Tags: android, greendroid

I'm trying to import GreenDroid into a new Android Project (SDK 2.2) and I'm getting this error while trying to clean my project and compile it:

Resource '/GreenDroid/gen' does not exist.

When I click on the GreenDroid project in the solution explorer, I'm also getting this error:

Project 'GreenDroid' is missing required source folder: 'gen'.

I would much appreciate your help on the matter.

Thanks!
Nicolas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure there are no build errors, then refresh the project, clean the project, and go to Android Tools-> Fix project properties. Some combination of those steps usually fixes my gen folder woes.

Comment: There was a problem with the library. Project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries. I removed the Android 2.2 and regenerated my project (Clean, Build All) and did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

goto the project properties and set android properties as Googleapi 2.2 or higher, but make sure the you have set the properties as GoogleApi only.